# A conjecture about binary palindromes and arithmetic derivatives

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, palindrome, arithmetic-derivative

Corrected question.

From the sequence of binary palindromes [A006995](https://oeis.org/A006995) (eg. 1001001001001) the sequence of possible gaps between consecutive palindromes contain the elements:

```
S={2,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,64,96,128,192,256,384,512,768,1024,1536,2048,3072,4096,6144,8192,12288,16384,24576,49152,...}
```

Compare with [A131117](http://oeis.org/A131117) that correspond to the set of positions of the records in the sequence of arithmetic derivatives.

```
T={2,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,64,96,128,192,256,384,512,640,768,960,1024,1280,1536,1920,2048,2560,3072,3584,3840,4096,5120,6144,7168,7680,8192,10240,12288,14336,15360,16384,20480,24576,28672,30720,32768,40960,...}
```

This prompts for the conjecture that $S\subseteq T$

A hint of a proof may be to much to ask for, but are there computational results that support or contradicts the conjecture?

$S$ comes from gaps of consecutive palindromes in the $100,000,000$ first palindromes $>0$.

Comment: I find this phrasing confusing; are you simply conjecturing that every element of A006995 is also an element of A131117?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  The sequence of binary palindromes starts as $\{0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 15, 17, 21, 27, 31, 33, 45, 51, 63, 65, 73, 85,\cdots\}$.  The gaps in that sequence look chaotic.   Can one say anything interesting about the set of those gaps?  I guess they are all even (except for the gap between $0$ and $1$).  Does every even number appear?  In any case, I have no idea what you are asking.   In particular, I am not clear what you are calling a "record".

Comment: So, what are some even integers that can't appear?

Comment: But for all you know those do occur somewhere?  I'd say that was the place to start.  Find $10$ as a gap somewhere, or prove that it can not occur.   Note:  $(7,17), (17,27), (21,31)$ and so on are all pairs of binary palindromes separated by $10$, though of course they are not consecutive pairs.

Comment: @lulu - The set $S$ only contain gaps  between consecutive palindromes.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  That's why I carefully pointed out that my pairs were not consecutive.  My point was that it was perfectly possible for both $n$ and $n+10$ to be binary palindromes.  Thus one would have to prove that, in such a case, at least one of $n+2,n+4,n+6,n+8$ was also a palindrome.  I don't see why that should be the case, but of course it might be.

Comment: Gaps between consecutive palindromes must have the form $2^k$ or $3 \cdot 2^k$.  To prove this, note that if a palindrome $n$ has a $0$ in the middle (or two $0$'s, if it's an even-digit palindrome), then the next palindrome replaces these $0$'s with $1$'s.  If $n$ has a string $01\cdots10$ in the middle, the next palindrome replaces this with $10\cdots01$.  If $n$ is all ones, the next palindrome is $n+2$.

Comment: @RaviFernando  Oh, thank you.  That's quite nice.

Comment: And I think that implies the result pretty easily.  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.  I'll first characterize the set $S$, and then show it's a subset of $T$.

Gaps between consecutive palindromes must have the form $2^k$ or $3\cdot 2^k$. To prove this, note that if a palindrome $n$ has a $0$ in the middle (or two $0$'s, if it's an even-digit palindrome), then the next palindrome replaces these $0$'s with $1$'s. If $n$ has a string $01 \cdots 10$ in the middle, the next palindrome replaces this with $10 \cdots 01$. If $n$ is all ones, the next palindrome is $n+2$.  In all cases, the differences have the specified form.  In fact, you can check conversely that $S$ consists of exactly the positive integers of the form $2^k$ or $3 \cdot 2^k$, excluding $3$, and also excluding $1$ if we don't allow $0$ as a palindrome.

Now I claim $S \subset T$.  Write $n$ as a product of not necessarily distinct primes, $n = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i$.  The arithmetic derivative of $n$ is then $n' = n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{p_i}$.  It follows that among all positive integers with at most $m$ prime divisors, the ones with the largest value of $\frac{n'}{n}$ are $2^m$ followed by $2^{m-1} \cdot 3$.  In particular, if $n = 2^m$, then every positive integer $a < n$ has fewer than $m$ prime divisors, so $\frac{a'}{a} < \frac{n'}{n}$ and thus $a' < n'$.  Similarly, if $n = 2^{m-1} \cdot 3$, then for every integer $a < n$ other than $a = 2^m$, we have $\frac{a'}{a} < \frac{n'}{n}$ and thus $a' < n'$; for $a = 2^m$ we have $a' = m \cdot 2^{m-1}$, which is less than $n' = (3m-1) \cdot 2^{m-2}$ provided that $m>1$.  So every number of the form $2^k$ or $2^k \cdot 3$ is in $T$, excluding $3$, and also excluding $1$ if we don't allow $1' = 0$ as a record.